# Tensorflow object detection model total loss starts out good, but suddenly explodes up to high loss numbers

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, training, object-detection

I'm training a Tensorflow object detection model with approx. 7500 images of two classes, which contains approx. 10,000 classes per class. I'm using Tensorflow 2.6.0, in case that is relavent. I am using Single Shot Detector (with a ResNet 50 backbone). The image dimensions are 1024 x 1024, and the batch size is set to 2. Training is being done on Ubuntu 20.04 with a GeForce RTX 2080 Super (GPU).

After beginning training, the process is starting out at loss numbers to be expected:

```
INFO:tensorflow:{'Loss/classification_loss': 2.1305692,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.6402807,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 1.407957,
 'Loss/total_loss': 4.178807,
 'learning_rate': 0.014666351}
I0903 16:56:21.947736 140581900665792 model_lib_v2.py:701] {'Loss/classification_loss': 2.1305692,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.6402807,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 1.407957,
 'Loss/total_loss': 4.178807,
 'learning_rate': 0.014666351}
INFO:tensorflow:Step 200 per-step time 0.447s
I0903 16:57:06.592366 140581900665792 model_lib_v2.py:698] Step 200 per-step time 0.447s
INFO:tensorflow:{'Loss/classification_loss': 1.2596315,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.6752764,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 3.0123177,
 'Loss/total_loss': 4.9472256,
 'learning_rate': 0.0159997}
I0903 16:57:06.592768 140581900665792 model_lib_v2.py:701] {'Loss/classification_loss': 1.2596315,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.6752764,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 3.0123177,
 'Loss/total_loss': 4.9472256,
 'learning_rate': 0.0159997}
INFO:tensorflow:Step 300 per-step time 0.452s
I0903 16:57:51.830375 140581900665792 model_lib_v2.py:698] Step 300 per-step time 0.452s
INFO:tensorflow:{'Loss/classification_loss': 1.0455683,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.5895866,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 3.0799737,
 'Loss/total_loss': 4.715129,
 'learning_rate': 0.01733305}
I0903 16:57:51.830749 140581900665792 model_lib_v2.py:701] {'Loss/classification_loss': 1.0455683,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.5895866,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 3.0799737,
 'Loss/total_loss': 4.715129,
 'learning_rate': 0.01733305}
```

Up until about step 16,800, the loss is decreasing to these numbers:

```
INFO:tensorflow:{'Loss/classification_loss': 0.5526215,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.28333753,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 0.24686696,
 'Loss/total_loss': 1.0828259,
 'learning_rate': 0.037849143}
I0903 18:59:14.666097 140581900665792 model_lib_v2.py:701] {'Loss/classification_loss': 0.5526215,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.28333753,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 0.24686696,
 'Loss/total_loss': 1.0828259,
 'learning_rate': 0.037849143}
INFO:tensorflow:Step 16700 per-step time 0.446s
I0903 18:59:59.247199 140581900665792 model_lib_v2.py:698] Step 16700 per-step time 0.446s
INFO:tensorflow:{'Loss/classification_loss': 0.4649979,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.28323257,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 0.2433301,
 'Loss/total_loss': 0.9915606,
 'learning_rate': 0.037820127}
I0903 18:59:59.247609 140581900665792 model_lib_v2.py:701] {'Loss/classification_loss': 0.4649979,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.28323257,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 0.2433301,
 'Loss/total_loss': 0.9915606,
 'learning_rate': 0.037820127}
INFO:tensorflow:Step 16800 per-step time 0.446s
I0903 19:00:43.835976 140581900665792 model_lib_v2.py:698] Step 16800 per-step time 0.446s
INFO:tensorflow:{'Loss/classification_loss': 0.43402833,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.1641234,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 0.24129395,
 'Loss/total_loss': 0.8394457,
 'learning_rate': 0.03779093}
I0903 19:00:43.836373 140581900665792 model_lib_v2.py:701] {'Loss/classification_loss': 0.43402833,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.1641234,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 0.24129395,
 'Loss/total_loss': 0.8394457,
 'learning_rate': 0.03779093}
```

However, starting at about 16,900, the model `total_loss` rapidly increases, up to numbers even higher than are shown below:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Step 16900 per-step time 0.446s
I0903 19:01:28.390861 140581900665792 model_lib_v2.py:698] Step 16900 per-step time 0.446s
INFO:tensorflow:{'Loss/classification_loss': 0.5590624,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.5160909,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 338.40286,
 'Loss/total_loss': 339.478,
 'learning_rate': 0.03776155}
I0903 19:01:28.391232 140581900665792 model_lib_v2.py:701] {'Loss/classification_loss': 0.5590624,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.5160909,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 338.40286,
 'Loss/total_loss': 339.478,
 'learning_rate': 0.03776155}
INFO:tensorflow:Step 17000 per-step time 0.445s
I0903 19:02:12.936022 140581900665792 model_lib_v2.py:698] Step 17000 per-step time 0.445s
INFO:tensorflow:{'Loss/classification_loss': 0.7908556,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.7274248,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 858.3554,
 'Loss/total_loss': 859.87366,
 'learning_rate': 0.037731986}
I0903 19:02:12.936432 140581900665792 model_lib_v2.py:701] {'Loss/classification_loss': 0.7908556,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.7274248,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 858.3554,
 'Loss/total_loss': 859.87366,
 'learning_rate': 0.037731986}
INFO:tensorflow:Step 17100 per-step time 0.452s
I0903 19:02:58.127156 140581900665792 model_lib_v2.py:698] Step 17100 per-step time 0.452s
INFO:tensorflow:{'Loss/classification_loss': 0.7510178,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.49337074,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 2617.2888,
 'Loss/total_loss': 2618.5332,
 'learning_rate': 0.03770224}
I0903 19:02:58.127575 140581900665792 model_lib_v2.py:701] {'Loss/classification_loss': 0.7510178,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.49337074,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 2617.2888,
 'Loss/total_loss': 2618.5332,
 'learning_rate': 0.03770224}
INFO:tensorflow:Step 17200 per-step time 0.445s
I0903 19:03:42.625258 140581900665792 model_lib_v2.py:698] Step 17200 per-step time 0.445s
INFO:tensorflow:{'Loss/classification_loss': 1.1258743,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.45634705,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 394886900.0,
 'Loss/total_loss': 394886900.0,
 'learning_rate': 0.037672307}
I0903 19:03:42.625638 140581900665792 model_lib_v2.py:701] {'Loss/classification_loss': 1.1258743,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.45634705,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 394886900.0,
 'Loss/total_loss': 394886900.0,
 'learning_rate': 0.037672307}
INFO:tensorflow:Step 17300 per-step time 0.445s
I0903 19:04:27.112154 140581900665792 model_lib_v2.py:698] Step 17300 per-step time 0.445s
INFO:tensorflow:{'Loss/classification_loss': 0.57859087,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.53405523,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 383440770.0,
 'Loss/total_loss': 383440770.0,
 'learning_rate': 0.037642203}
I0903 19:04:27.112533 140581900665792 model_lib_v2.py:701] {'Loss/classification_loss': 0.57859087,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.53405523,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 383440770.0,
 'Loss/total_loss': 383440770.0,
 'learning_rate': 0.037642203}
```

What could be the cause of this, and what would be the best way to go about fixing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic "exploding gradient" problem. You can try adding gradient clipping or increasing the amount of regularization.

Decreasing the learning rate, or increasing the batch size may also help.